# Putting box-shadow on site-wrapper

Tags: html, css

Here's the page that I'm having trouble with. You can see that when I scroll down the shadow is in the wrong place. http://michaelaharvey.github.io/

I'm trying to make my page have have box-shadow css property. However, I can't seem to make box-shadow apply to the entire webpage. As a result, when I scroll down there is a shadow in the middle of the page when there shouldn't be. I tried using...
     #site-wrapper {overflow: hidden;}

...but that caused my page-jump navigation to break. How can I set the div height of site-wrapper equal to the entire page, including all the overflow? Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make one more element that wraps up the `.cover-container`

```
<div class="site-wrapper-inner">
    <div class="cover-wrapper">
         <div class="cover-container">
             ....
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

then place its CSS like

```
.cover-wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

since you use `table` and `table-cell` in `.site-wrapper` and `.site-wrapper-inner`

so you must add something to wrap the content in order to control its height